# NGINX Reverse Proxy for JupyterHub inside docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, jupyterhub

I want to config nginx as a reverse proxy on my host ubuntu VM to point to the jupyterhub running inside a docker on port 8888. I am using subpaths for this and not subdomains and my corporate firewall gives me access only to port 80 and 443, all other ports are blocked, that's why i can't use rewrite. I came up with the following nginx configuration, which works but it does not display the assets from jupyter hub(css files, images and so on)
The path myservername.com/jphubdisplays the page but the assets are loaded from myservername.com (without the subpath /jphub)
Ex(the logo is loaded from myservername.com/hub/logo instead of myservername.com/jphub/hub/logo.

Does anyone know if i am doing this the right way? what should i change inside the config?

```
upstream jupyter {
        server localhost:8888;
        keepalive 32;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myservername.com;
  ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/cert-request/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key; 
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location /jphub/ {
    proxy_pass http://jupyter/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect / /jphub/;
proxy_redirect  http://jupyter/ https://$host/jphub/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    add_header       X-Upstream      $upstream_addr;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `location` path ends in `/`, Nginx removes the leading part before forwarding the request.

To have it forward the full path, remove the trailing `/`, so you have

```
location /jphub {
  ...
  ...
}
```

in your Nginx configuration.

Comment: i also tried that and it's not working